# CodeBlocks in a Xenial

Tags: apt, 16.04, development, ide, code-blocks

I'm newbie in linux and I can't install the codeblocks in the xenial.
These errors happen:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

codeblocks: 
    Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 16.01~ubuntu16.04.1) but 16.01~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
    Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
    Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1+dfsg2) but it is not going to be installedcd
    Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1+dfsg2) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: codeblocks-common (= 16.01~ubuntu16.04.1) but 16.01~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
```

I've installed the 3.0 version of wx.

Tks

Comment: It seems like you are trying to install a different version of codeblocks than the one that is available in the repositories.  Why don't you use that one?

Comment: To explain: your version depends on wx 2.8, while Xenial has wx 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xenial dumped wxWidgets 2.8, it's not even in repositories. code::blocks  won't work on it, unless a version compiled with 3.0 is made available (and Jen's version won't work, it requires more recent libs than those available on  hte repositories) or 2.8 is added  back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two way to solve this issue:

1. Run the following command that should fix (and install) missing packages on which *Codeblock* depends:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
2. Install manually missing packages with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libcodeblocks0 libgcc1 libwxbase2.8 libwxgtk2.8 codeblocks-common
   ```

---

More info about apt-get command can be found reading the manual:

```
man apt-get
```

I hope this could help you.